# How to solve if an integer has an integer root?

Tags: php, algorithm, math, floating-accuracy

I need to solve for any root of degree n that it has an integer root. My initial idea was to find the approximate root using Newton's method, however, would the power function not give us the maximum accuracy that can be expressed by the machine's floats?

```
function hasIntegerRoot( $integer, $degree ) {
    if( $degree == 0 || $degree == 1 ) return true;

    $r = pow( $integer, 1/$degree );

    //get nearest integer
    $n = round($r);

    //solve n^x
    $answer = pow( $n, $degree );

    return $answer == $integer;
}
```

I have two questions:

Does the power function solve sufficiently close to the integer root such that rounding the float will never return the wrong integer root? This would require it to be off by 0.5, which intuitively I could not imagine happening, but I have no arduous proof.

Secondly, does the return statement require decimal math? The issue is that for sufficiently large $integer and $n, PHP will use float. This is desirable in that it will not overflow large integers; however, it leaves use with floating point math, which inherently has inaccuracies. Would those inaccuracies affect my algorithm though?

Again, intuitively I feel like the constraints that $integer is an integer and that the root $n must be an integer avoids any floating point math issues. The math would never involve decimals. However, I have no way to absolutely prove the intuition.

Comment: The fact that you're using `pow()` and reciprocals means that you're involving floats.

Comment: You can use BC Math fucntions which supports numbers of any size and precision, **but** represented as strings

Answer (score 0):

I woudn't rely on pow() being accurate enough for this, but you could certainly start with pow(...,1/degree) and then walk $n up or down until $n**$degree matches or crosses $integer.  (But implement ** degree yourself, since internally it uses pow())

pow() is an approximation that doesn't always return the closest possible value to the exact result